# Removing the く when pronouncing 洗濯機(せんたくき)

Tags: pronunciation, gemination

At [2m34s](https://youtu.be/H7nRAKcrZGY?t=156), the speaker seems to pronounce 洗濯機 not with a devoiced く, but a complete removal of it.

That is, it sounds to me like she's saying せんたき{LHHL} instead of seNTAK_ki.

**Question:** Is this a legitimate pronunciation of this word? Or is this only the way you might pronounce the word to children or new Japanese learners?

I found a clip of [Dogen](https://youtu.be/NmP9xyihBBQ?t=64) pronouncing it as "seNTAK_ki", but he can't be trusted since he's not a native speaker :)

Comment: The transcript shows "交代交代します これは**洗濯機**です" at 2m34s for me. It's just an error?

Comment: There she says せんたっき. I was expecting your link to be pointing at the right time became that's how you have done it.

Comment: Dogen pronounces the first /k/ as a plosive, with a little release of air, and then says the second /k/ with no vowel in between. It’s totally unnecessary and that’s not how most native speakers pronounce it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She pronounced it as **せんたっき**, not せんたき. According to NHK, this is an acceptable pronunciation of the word. The く was not removed, but **replaced with the small tsu**!

This is a phenomenon called 促音化 (gemination). You probably already know that 学校 is formally spelled and pronounced as がっこう instead of がくこう.

せんたっき is in the same vein, but it's still in the middle of the full gemination process. That is, all dictionaries and most people say the correct *spelling* is せんたくき, but more than half of the people actually *pronounce* it as せんたっき almost unconsciously. (But せんたくき is still correct, of course.)

You can read about gemination in the following articles:

- [最近気になる放送用語：「洗濯機」はセンタクキ？ センタッキ？](https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/research/kotoba/20190301_4.html)
- [Imabi: Sokuonka](https://www.imabi.net/sokuonka.htm)

[This](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/97854/5010) is a similar phenomenon.

(By the way, if you missed the small tsu that was there, that means you need to train your ears! せんたき and せんたっき are as different as night and day to Japanese ears, and she pronounced it really clearly in the video.)

Comment: This is fascinating! RE NHK, I checked my version (Android app) of the dictionary and only see [this](https://imgur.com/a/kafNlYX). Is the pronunciation guideline you're referring to in the index/appendices?

Comment: @George [This article](https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/research/kotoba/20190301_4.html) is from NHK.