# Is す devoiced in おすそわけ?

Tags: pronunciation, gemination

At [29s of this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OaIhIScRAVA&t=29s), it sounds to me like おすそわけ is being said like oS_SOWAKE instead of oSUSOWAKE.

Both OJAD and Wiktionary don't indicate that there's any devoicing going on with this word though, so I'm worried I just am mishearing this.

So is す sometimes (or always?) devoiced with this word?

Comment: おおっ「おっそわけ」ほんまや！「ごちそうさん」「せんたくき」も早く言うと「ごっそさん」(「ごchそうさん」?）「せんたっき」になるやんな～

Comment: Related, perhaps? -> https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/99917/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/33742/9831 ←「すいぞっかん」。「ごうせっちたい」？へ～

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly certain that there is a rise in pitch on the そ, which suggests that the す is devoiced.

Comment: Does that mean the true pitch of the word is oSSOwake (Nakadaka)?

Comment: Susowake is atonic, so it's pitch contour would be LHHH (I assume you understand this way of representing a contour). Addition of 'o' would mean that the contour would be LHHHH, but what I can hear is L(L)HHH, by which I mean the second syllable doesn't bear a tone, being devoiced, as you noticed.

Comment: I have to confess that I didn't know what 'nakadaka' was since it isn't used in the literature I've read, but it seems that it means the occurrence of an accent within the word; susowake is atonic, adding o simply creates a new, atonic word.