# Term for "Letter"/Symbol name vs. pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, linguistics, comparative-linguistics

I was trying to explain to someone why spelling & reading in Japanese (at least with kana) is easy because the name of the letter ***is*** its pronuncation.  (Yes, I realize kana are not strictly "letters", but for the sake of brevity...)

| Kana | Name | Pronunciation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| た | "tah" | "tah" |
| み | "mee" | "mee" |
| etc. |  |  |

So if you can see a word or sentence (particles aside), you know exactly how to pronounce it.  Conversely, if you can hear/say a word, you know exactly how to spell it.

However, English and many other languages are not like this.  The letter's name is completely different than how you'd say it.

| Letter | Name | Pronunciation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | "ay" | "ah", "ah", "a(nt)" |
| B | "bee" | "b-" |
| C | "see" | "k-", "s-" |
| etc. |  |  |

---

Is there some linguistic term (in Japanese, or any language) around this name/pronunciation relationship?  And if so, are there terms that encompass the sameness of Japanese relationship, and the difference of English one?

Comment: This question seems better suited for the Linguistics SE.

Comment: I didn't realize they were the **names** of the characters. I've thought we are just reading them.

Comment: @aguijonazo, 例えば「ひらがなの『た』」といえば、文字について話しているとは明らかではないですか。  Or would you talk about the kana themselves in some other fashion?  (Honest question.)

Comment: @aguijonazo Although you maybe have actual **names** for some of them, like 「そくおん」 or 「ちいさいつ」 for 「 っ 」...

Comment: Regarding istrasci's original question about terms for letter / sound relationships, I have not heard such terms, but if I had to invent them, then maybe: *homoliterophony* (noun), *homoliterophonic* (adjective), *heteroliterophony* (noun), *heteroliterophonic* (adjective) :) .

Comment: I think this is a natural consequence from the difference between alphabetic scripts (with distinct letters for each vowel and consonant) and syllabic scripts (with distinct letters for each consonant-vowel combination). It would be difficult to spell out "strength" without using the distinct names of each character, but Japanese has no such problem (well, basically... we do need "ちいさいつ" and so on sometimes).

Comment: @naruto It is not too hard to pronounce a single-consonant word. They exist in some languages, e.g. Czech language has <k> pronounced [k], <s> pronounced [s], <v> pronounced [v], <z> pronounced [z].

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi - Those characters are referred to by their readings when necessary. If you call them names, I guess they are. I'm just saying I've never seen it that way.

Comment: @Arfrever - そくおん doesn't refer to a character but a sound, or a phonetic phenomenon.

Comment: The original question aside, I think the Name column should be removed from the table.

Comment: @aguijonazo If you have to say "「っ」を書いて" aloud to somebody, how will you read it? そくおんきごう, そくおんもじ?

Comment: @Arfrever - 小さい「つ」, of course. For my stand on つ, read my reply to Eiríkr Útlendi.

Comment: It is also interesting to think why the phonetic code (such as alpha, bravo, charlie...) cannot be a name of alphabet. I think this is simply because people treat "names" as a privileged way of indicating each letter for historical and cultural reasons.

Comment: I personally feel that indicating letters (hiragana and katakana) by its reading is not a privileged way, even though quite common in Japanese. This feeling may arise from 1. some letters are hard to be pronounced by themselves (e.g. 「っ」,「ー」) 2. some pairs of letters are no longer distinctive in quite a few speakers' pronunciation (e.g.「じ」and「ぢ」,「お」and「を」) 3. hiragana and katakana is not distinctive on pronunciation 4. analogy to the ways used to indicate kanjis.

Comment: One could argue that the fact that (when distinction is necessary) じ and ぢ are commonly referred to as 「し」に点々 and 「ち」に点々, respectively, is an indication that they don't have names as such.

Comment: Also in Japanese, a single letter can represent multiple sounds like [ん](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/97854/45489).  I guess names/pronunciation are not exactly related. It's rather that there're sounds first, then letters that represent them, then those letters have names.

Answer (score 1):

In linguistics, the consistency of pronunciation for each letter or character in a language like Japanese Katakana or Hindi is referred to as "**phonemic orthography**." This term describes a writing system where each symbol (or letter) consistently represents the same sound (or phoneme). In languages with phonemic orthography, there's a direct and consistent correspondence between the written symbols and their pronunciation, which makes it easier to predict how a word is pronounced based on its spelling.

In contrast, languages like English, which have a high degree of variation in how letters are pronounced in different contexts, are said to have a "**deep orthography**." This means there's a complex relationship between spelling and pronunciation, with many exceptions and irregularities.

Thus, the key term here is "phonemic orthography," describing the straightforward, predictable relationship between spelling and pronunciation in languages like Japanese (when written in Katakana) and Hindi.